# error: lvalue required as increment operand

Tags: c, lvalue

I tried the following code:

```
int a = ++2;
```

I am aware that a constant cannot be modified, but I cannot understand the error that the compiler outputs:

```
*  error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

What exactly does it mean?

Comment: You can't increment a constant. It should be like a+=2. Error is simple that increment operation should be performed over left hand values , and left hand values are  variables.

Comment: If this code worked, then all future uses of `2` would be `3`! There are ++4 lights!

Comment: It is how compiler is telling you that: _constant cant increment directly_

Comment: Where does this stuff come from?

Answer (score 4):

An expression is considered an "lvalue" when it designates a modifiable location in memory. Operators which modify a value require that their operand is an lvalue.

Assignment operators require that the left-hand side is an lvalue. This is where this jargon originates from. Postfix and prefix increment/decrement operators also have this requirement for their single operand.

An lvalue expression may not be just a variable name, but also a more complex expression, for example:

```
*(p + 2); // the unary * operator produces an lvalue
*(p + 2) = 5; // so that this is possible
(*(p + 2))++; // or this
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly it means is that

1. `++` is by definition an **increment operator** (an operator that increments)
2. The thing it operates on is called the **increment operand**
3. This thing is required to be an **lvalue** (something that amounts to a pointer)
4. In this case `2` is the **increment operator** and it is not an **lvalue**.